# How to include empty field values in query count when the value in a second field has a certain value for a given period (3rd field)

Tags: sql, oracle

My query needs to display, for each student, for each financial award received, the number of terms (semesters) the student was enrolled full time (greater than or equal to 12 hours) whether or not the award was received that semester PLUS the number of terms the student was enrolled part time (less than 12 hours, but greater than 1 hour) AND the student received the award. Currently, I can only get the query to count the number of terms each award was received.

For example, let's say that the student with the ID of 000001 has the following awards and enrollment (displayed by term):

```
            | AWARD_111 | AWARD_222 | AWARD_333 | AWARD_444 | HRS_ENROLLED
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
FALL_2015   |     Y     |           |     Y     |           |      15
SPRING_2016 |     Y     |           |     Y     |           |      13
FALL_2016   |     Y     |           |     Y     |     Y     |      17
SPRING_2017 |     Y     |           |     Y     |     Y     |      15
FALL_2017   |     Y     |           |     Y     |           |      17
SPRING_2018 |     Y     |           |     Y     |           |      15
SUMMER_2018 |           |           |           |           |       3
FALL_2018   |     Y     |     Y     |     Y     |           |      15
SPRING_2019 |     Y     |     Y     |     Y     |           |      17
SUMMER_2019 |           |     Y     |           |           |       1
FALL_2019   |           |           |     Y     |           |      12
```

The result I'm currently getting is this (just showing for the one student above):

```
STUDENT_ID | AWARD_CODE | AWARD_COUNT
-------------------------------------
000001     | AWARD_1111 |      8
000001     | AWARD_2222 |      3
000001     | AWARD_3333 |      9
000001     | AWARD_4444 |      2
```

The result I want is:

```
STUDENT_ID | AWARD_CODE | AWARD_COUNT
-------------------------------------
000001     | AWARD_1111 |      9
000001     | AWARD_2222 |     10
000001     | AWARD_3333 |      9
000001     | AWARD_4444 |      9
```

Here is my stripped-down query (actually, one of many completely different types of queries I tried that each produced the same wrong results):

```sql
  SELECT TERM.STUDENT_ID AS STUDENT_ID,
         AWARDS_FUND_CODE AS AWARD_CODE,
         SUM ( CASE WHEN TERM.HRS_ENROLLED >= 12
                    THEN 1
                    WHEN ( ( TERM.HRS_ENROLLED >= 1 ) AND ( AWARDS.STUDENT_ID = TERM.STUDENT_ID ) )
                    THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
             END ) AS AWARD_COUNT
    FROM ( SELECT ENROLLMENT_STUDENT_ID AS STUDENT_ID,
                  ENROLLMENT_TERM_CODE AS TERM_CODE,
                  ENROLLMENT_ENROLLED_HRS AS HRS_ENROLLED
             FROM ENROLLMENT
            WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT AWARDS_FUND_CODE
                             FROM AWARDS
                            WHERE ENROLLMENT_STUDENT_ID = AWARDS_STUDENT_ID ) )     TERM,
         AWARDS
   WHERE TERM.STUDENT_ID = AWARDS_STUDENT_ID
     AND TERM.TERM_CODE = AWARDS_TERM_CODE
GROUP BY TERM.STUDENT_ID, AWARDS_FUND_CODE
ORDER BY AWRDS_FUND_CODE
```

Comment: So do the columns  `AWARD_111`, `AWARD_222` etc. allow `NULL` values?  And your data for those columns `Y` or `NULL`?

Comment: This above query is used to create a view that stores the values. The AWARD_CODE column in this view does allow for NULL values. However, the AWARDS_FUND_CODE column in the AWARDS table that the AWARD_CODE column gets its values from does not allow for NULL values.

Comment: So does your view return a `NULL` for `AWARD_333` if the value in the base table is not `Y`?  You have to be careful with `NULL` values if so; IE: `where award_333 [!]= null` does not work as many people (initially) assume but `where award_333 is [not] null` does.

Comment: No, if a value for AWARD_333 in the base table is not Y, the view does not return a NULL. The view simply doesn't acknowledge what doesn't exist. I wish the base table did have NULL values. Then, at least, there would be something to count.

Answer (score 0):

As usual, the difficult part was setting up the test data. I will leave the end pivot to you.

```
WITH
    aset AS
        (SELECT 1               sortval
              , 'FALL_2015'     AS quarter
              , 'Y'             AS award_111
              , NULL            AS award_222
              , 'Y'             AS award_333
              , NULL            AS award_444
              , 15              AS hours_enrolled
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2, 'SPRING_2016', 'Y', NULL, 'Y', NULL, 13 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 3, 'FALL_2016', 'Y', NULL, 'Y', 'Y', 17 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 4, 'SPRING_2017', 'Y', NULL, 'Y', 'Y', 15 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 5, 'FALL_2017', 'Y', NULL, 'Y', NULL, 17 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 6, 'SPRING_2018', 'Y', NULL, 'Y', NULL, 15 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 7, 'SUMMER_2018', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 3 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 8, 'FALL_2018', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', NULL, 15 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 9, 'SPRING_2019', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', NULL, 17 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 10, 'SUMMER_2019', NULL, 'Y', NULL, NULL, 1 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 11, 'FALL_2019', NULL, NULL, 'Y', NULL, 12 FROM DUAL),
    bset AS( SELECT aset.*, '00001' AS student_id FROM aset ),
    cset AS
        (  SELECT COUNT( award_111 )     AS cnt_111
                , COUNT( award_222 )     AS cnt_222
                , COUNT( award_333 )     AS cnt_333
                , COUNT( award_444 )     AS cnt_444
                , student_id
             FROM bset
         GROUP BY student_id),
    dset AS
        (SELECT bset.*
              , cnt_111
              , cnt_222
              , cnt_333
              , cnt_444
           FROM cset
                INNER JOIN bset ON cset.student_id = bset.student_id)
  SELECT SUM( CASE WHEN cnt_111 > 0 AND (hours_enrolled >= 12 OR award_111 = 'Y') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )    AS award_111
       , SUM( CASE WHEN cnt_222 > 0 AND (hours_enrolled >= 12 OR award_222 = 'Y') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )    AS award_222
       , SUM( CASE WHEN cnt_333 > 0 AND (hours_enrolled >= 12 OR award_333 = 'Y') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )    AS award_333
       , SUM( CASE WHEN cnt_444 > 0 AND (hours_enrolled >= 12 OR award_444 = 'Y') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )    AS award_444
    FROM dset
GROUP BY student_id
ORDER BY student_id
```

This results in the following output

```
AWARD_111   AWARD_222   AWARD_333   AWARD_444
9           10          9           9
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that ultimately worked:

```
  SELECT TERM.STUDENT_ID AS STUDENT_ID,
         ENROLLMENT.FUND_CODE AS FUND_CODE,
         SUM( ENROLLMENT.COUNTER ) AS AWARD_COUNT
    FROM ( SELECT ENROLLMENT_STUDENT_ID AS STUDENT_ID,
                  ENROLLMENT_TERM_CODE AS TERM_CODE,
                  ENROLLMENT_ENROLLED_HRS AS HRS_ENROLLED,
                  FUND.FUND_CODE            FUND_CODE,
                  CASE WHEN ENROLLMENT_ENROLLED_HRS >= 12
                       THEN 1
                       WHEN ENROLLMENT_ENROLLED_HRS >= 1
                       THEN 1
                       ELSE 0
                  END COUNTER
             FROM ENROLLMENT,
                  ( SELECT TERM_AWARD_STUDENT_ID AS STUDENT_ID,
                           TERM_AWARD_FUND_CODE AS FUND_CODE
                      FROM TERM_AWARD
                  GROUP BY TERM_AWARD_STUDENT_ID, TERM_AWARD_FUND_CODE ) FUND
            WHERE ENROLLMENT_STUDENT_ID = FUND.STUDENT_ID
         ORDER BY FUND.FUND_CODE, ENROLLMENT_TERM_CODE ) TERM,
         ( SELECT TERM_AWARD_STUDENT_ID AS STUDENT_ID,
                  TERM_AWARD_PERIOD AS PERIOD,
                  TERM_AWARD_FUND_CODE AS FUND_CODE
             FROM TERM_AWARD,
                  ENROLLMENT
            WHERE TERM_AWARD_STUDENT_ID = ENROLLMENT_STUDENT_ID
              AND TERM_AWARD_PERIOD = ENROLLMENT_TERM_CODE ) AWARD
   WHERE ENROLLMENT.PIDM = AWARD.PIDM (+)
     AND ENROLLMENT.TERM_CODE = AWARD.PERIOD (+)
     AND ENROLLMENT.FUND_CODE = AWARD.FUND_CODE (+)
GROUP BY ENROLLMENT.PIDM, ENROLLMENT.FUND_CODE
ORDER BY ENROLLMENT.PIDM, ENROLLMENT.FUND_CODE
```